# huge memory usage in static class

Tags: c#, string, memory-leaks, crash-dumps

I have a static list

```
List<Tuple<string, string>> binariesList = new List<Tuple<string, string>>()
```

in an static class called `Class1`.

The non-static class `Class2` use `Class1` a lot of times. Instances of `Class2` are constructed often, I think there is no problem with that (Garbage Collcetor collects it).

But just at start of program, `Class1` loads a file of about 2 MB into `binariesList`.

In the static `load()` method I use this for loading for each element:

```
dic.Add(new Tuple<string,string>(temp[i].Split(',')[1].Trim(), temp[i].Split(',')[0].Trim()));
```

I have a memory problem and saw there is a high reference count and size(bytes) columns, in the memory dump I analyze for that  `Tuple<string,string>`.

Is there a problem with that `Tuple<string,string>`?

[image]

Comment: *2mg file* loading? Umm that's doesn't sound efficient. Instead read line by line and do processing.

Comment: No. that's not the solution and won't solve the problem

Comment: How many lines are you iterating over? Seems like you're potentially generating alot of strings.

Comment: It's almost impossible to diagnose your issue with a single line of code, and not much information. You also just tell us you have a 'memory problem', but not any more details further than that.

Comment: @Rob I added a picture of memory dump analyze. hope it will help

Comment: What memory problem do you have? Post some relevant code. Provide better context of the issue you are facing. What have you tried to solve the issue?

Comment: the main exe of program gets more memory, about 300 mg after working long time. I think garbage collector cant collect it, cause of many requests and interaction with program.

Answer (score 0):

That's not a memory leak I'd say. It's the intended behavior of your program as far as I can tell from your question.

The problem is neither with the `Tuple` nor with the `List` - it's the way you use the list to add items to it.

To avoid crashing due to an `OutOfMemoryException`, simply remove items from the list that are not needed any more.

Comment: All items Are needed in from start to end of program. I use them for checking some values. and items won't increase or decrease until end. I think problem is architecture using this access method. maybe something better than tuple or static is not used correctly in this place

Comment: If the items are used from the beginning to the end, it doesn't matter whether they are static or not from memory point of view. The objects will always be *rooted*. However, from a design or architectural point of view, there may be better solutions.

Comment: so will you offer better architecture designs for more reading and getting new ideas from that

Comment: @Hamed_gibago: no. That's something for [programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/tour)